# How to install opencl on kubuntu 16?

Tags: 16.04, c++, opencl

I executed command below:

```
apt-get -f install ocl-icd-libopencl1
```

But I get an error.
Sorry, my language version is polish

```
[
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Wymaga: linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic ale nie zostanie zainstalowany
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-70-generic : Wymaga: linux-image-4.15.0-70-generic ale nie zostanie zainstalowany lub
                                                 linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-70-generic ale nie zostanie zainstalowany
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-88-generic : Wymaga: linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic ale nie zostanie zainstalowany lub
                                                 linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-88-generic ale nie zostanie zainstalowany
E: Niespełnione zależności. Proszę spróbować wykonać "apt-get -f install" bez pakietów (lub podać rozwiązanie).
]
```

My translate to english:

```
[
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Require: linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic but will not be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-70-generic : Required: linux-image-4.15.0-70-generic but will not be installed or
                                                 linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-70-generic but will not be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-88-generic : Required: linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic but will not be installed or
                                                 linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-88-generic but will not be installed
E: Unfulfilled dependencies. 
]
```

The version of my linux is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux SSDB 4.15.0-69-generic #78~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 8 11:20:31 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Kubuntu is a desktop OS, and Ubuntu server and desktop releases use a *yy.mm* format, thus there is no Kubuntu 16.

Comment: FYI: Kubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Kubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Comment: Your system should have reported 16.04.6 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) and not 16.04.5 so you're likely behind on your upgrades.  As previously suggested I would recommend you look at the output of `ubuntu-support-status` as much of your system is EOL.  From the link is "*Maintenance updates are provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, Ubuntu Base, and Ubuntu Kylin. All the remaining flavours are supported for 3 years.*"  Your base packages are supported yes, but your GUI/applications are no longer supported as Kubuntu is EOL.